# Optimizing INSERT performance for large MariaDB table with sequence primary key

Tags: optimization, mariadb

I have this MariaDB/MySQL table with a multi-column primary key that includes a sequence `id`.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE events_id_sequence;
CREATE TABLE events(
    id bigint unsigned DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR events_id_sequence) NOT NULL,
    saved_at timestamp(4) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    thing_id bigint(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
    event_id smallint unsigned NOT NULL,
...
    PRIMARY KEY (thing_id DESC, id DESC)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB, ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

I have imported test data into this table and observed that with a few million rows, each subsequent INSERT takes progressively more time to complete. The data was inserted in batches of 1000 events.

I expect the table to contain around 200 million rows in 12 months, and I intend to remove old events after that. The table includes about 20k different `thing_id`s, and it will mainly be used for INSERTs and SELECTs like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE thing_id=<X> AND ... ORDERED BY id DESC LIMIT <Y>;
```

I make the primary key to cluster events from the same source (`thing_id`) together and order events in reverse insertion order.

I have the following questions regarding the decrease in INSERT performance:

1. Is my concern about slow INSERTs unavoidable as the table grows large and MariaDB has to check the primary index for uniqueness?
2. Will using the `AUTO_INCREMENT` type make any performance difference?
3. Can someone suggest a more optimal schema or strategy for my task?
4. Should I consider partitioning the table?
5. What MariaDB configuration options are worth checking to increase INSERT performance?

Answer (score 1):

Consider this change to your my.cnf or my.ini in [mysqld] section,

```
innodb_change_buffer_max_size=50  # to achieve additional INSERT speed.
```

Note, you may have to add this line.

Stop/start time the INSERT of 1000 rows for duration before and after.

Additional possibility,

```
SELECT @@innodb_write_io_threads;  to determine current number of threads
```

Double the write thead count.

The BEST always.

Comment: @Sokolof        Has your INSERT performance improved?  Suggestions applied? View profile, please.